# How electromagnetic force makes the collision?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, classical-mechanics

What makes matter collide?. I guess electromagnetic force, one of 4 fundamental forces, makes collision. If it is, in the equal distribution of electric charge, matters will go through each other and collide will never happen. Then what causes collision? Is it a appliance of same principle of Rutherford gold foil experiment?

Comment: Are you talking about collisions between charged particles? And to note, matter doesn’t really go *through* each other. A better worded question would be very helpful.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not good at english. I mean the collision in the newton scale. All atoms are electrically neutral, then how the collision would happen without going through each other?

Comment: I understand now. Thank you. Writing an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atoms on overall are electrically neutral but you asked how they interact then when they collide. It’s wrong to assume from the Rutherford experiment because he used a thin *Gold-foil* which are very large and only *alpha particles* or Helium **nuclei** were fired but when **atoms** collide they have a huge boundary of *electron shells*. Hence when it’s an atom-atom collision there is indeed repulsion between the electron clouds that are the shells of the atom and hence they can interact with each other such as bounce off elastically such as for gas atoms.

But for the Rutherford experiment the Alpha particles had no electron shells hence most of them were undeviated as they were also very small compared to the radius of the whole atom. Hence it’s a different scenario when atoms **with** shells colliding. They just have a higher chance of interacting as atoms are more comparable to each other in-terms of size and both have negative charge on the outside so the positive nuclei rarely effect collision outcomes.

Comment: Thank you for answer. You mean that repulsion between electrons are bigger than attraction between electrons and protons.  Then spatial distance causes the difference between two forces?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you do the math even with quantum effects, it will give the same conclusion.